# How to detect and interact with a device in silent mode using Adobe air - AS3

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing a game with background sounds using as3 - adobe air. I recently discovered that if the device is Silent, the music will keep playing, either on iOS or Android. I need to know is there any way that : 
- Detects at launch if originally the silent switch is clicked (Silent mode enabled) 
- Detects at any time if the silent switch is clicked

At any time, i need the app to be responsive to the user silence interaction. How can i do this? i've searched all over the internet but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This ANE is your choice http://www.myflashlabs.com/product/volume-control-adobe-air-native-extension-pro-version/ - it lets you handle any volume manipulations

Comment: thank you for your answer, so there is no native as3 free way to just get silence switch behavior?

Comment: Haven't heard of any, but these 20$ will save you some hours of time googling or a number of days on ANE implementation